# cannot login ubuntu desktop after change passwd

Tags: 14.04, login-screen

Yesterday I changed passwd with recovery mode. After I resumed normal boot, it only shows guest session and other but not my account. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: try it on tty mode `alt + ctrl + f2` and tell what happenes

Comment: open terminal after ı do login there -bash: /etc/profile:permission denied i have no name

Comment: there not have anybody to help me plz

Comment: anybody not there to hel me plz 3 day i do manythisg but stil same plz help

Comment: do you have root login enabled ? then please try to login as root

Comment: how to login plz ım new to forum ı dont know much sorry

Comment: press `alt+ctrl+f2` and type **root** for `username` and your `password`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the password by editing the /etc/shadow file

have a look at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700690/how-do-i-completely-remove-root-password